# Orbeon forms - how to change default behaviour of Orbeon Action

Tags: javascript, forms, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud

Currently in **Orbeon Forms**, when you define an **Orbeon Action** which would (for example) react to a value being changed on the form, you can specify which **Service** does that Action call while providing some input parameters. Also, you can specify what you want to do with Service response and how you want to use the data received, e.g. to maybe populate some other form field.

I have a situation where Orbeon forms are used as a part of Hybris Commerce Suite, and I need to trigger the Service call after some fields change, then perform the logic on server-side and **reload** the original page (where form is located). Since **Orbeon Builder** doesn't offer me that functionality, can you give me some hints/inputs of how can this be achieved?

In other words, can I override the default Orbeon Builder functionality to let me reload the page when a response is received from the server? If I was using regular HTML forms with JS/JQuery this wouldn't be an issue, I'm just not sure how Orbeon handles this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify: are you sure you want the service call and page reload to happen when the user changes a value? You wouldn't want users clicking on a button to trigger that action? I am asking as it is unusual to navigate away from the current page, even if it is just to reload it, when users just change a value in a field.

Comment: And in case you wonder, this is where I'm going with this: I'd suggest you define a process that does what you described, and tied to a button at the bottom of the form. In the process, you'd use the `send()` and `navigate()` action. http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes.html

Comment: @avernet actually, what I need is to reload a part of the page after user changes the input values on Orbeon form. That part of page which needs to be reloaded **isn't part of the Form** (on the page, besides Orbeon form, I have separate section displaying some data calculated on the server side which is influenced by user input). 

This server-logic is triggered when different fields on the form change, and because of that dynamic behaviour (and since it is a customer requirement), I cant use button to trigger it. Thanks, I'll check the link, but I'm not sure if it will work for this case

Comment: OK, if the part of the page that you want to reload isn't part of the form, I understand why it makes sense for that to happen just on value change. So using a process won't work for you, since processes are triggered by users hitting a button. I suggest you define your service and action, as you seem to have done already, and edit the source to add the following, e.g. before the `</xf:model>`: `<xxf:script observer="my-service-submission" ev:event="xforms-submit-done">alert(42);</xxf:script>`.

Comment: This assume your service is named `my-service`; update the code accordingly based on your service name, and JavaScript code you want to call. Would this work for you?

Comment: Yes, that should do it. Thanks a lot @avernet

Comment: OK, great, then I posted this as answer to your question below, to make it easier for people who find this to figure what the solution is without going through comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Form Builder [services](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/http-services.html) and [actions](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/actions.html), to plugin your own JavaScript after the service ran, in Form Builder, [edit the source of the form](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/edit-source.html), and add the following before the `</xf:model>`:

```
<xxf:script observer="my-service-submission"
    ev:event="xforms-submit-done">alert('gaga');</xxf:script>.
```

In the `observer` attribute, replace `my-service` by the name you gave to your service (keeping the `-submission` suffix). And of course, replace `alert('gaga')` by the actual JavaScript code you'd like to run.